# How to import data from multiple ranges defined by two columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need help with importing multiple ranges into one block from two defining columns - one column defines the links, the second one defines the sheets.

Table 1 looks something like this:

```
  | Link to spreadsheet   | Sheet Name |
1 | docs.google/blahblah  | Team 1     |
2 | docs.google/blahblah2 | Team 2     |
3 | docs.google/blahblah3 | Team 3     |
```

I need to import data from columns C:E from these sheets, from those sheet names, so it'd look something like this:

```
  | C                               | D     | E     |
1 | some value from blahblah Team 1 | ditto | ditto |
1 | some value from blahblah Team 1 | ditto | ditto |
1 | some value from blahblah Team 1 | ditto | ditto |
1 | some value from blahblah Team 2 | ditto | ditto |
1 | some value from blahblah Team 2 | ditto | ditto |
1 | some value from blahblah Team 3 | ditto | ditto |
```

I already know how to import one range using the cells(I do it like this):
`QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(A2:A, "'"&A2:A&"'"&"!C:E"), "select *")`
but I don't know how to expand this approach into import from entire column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would go like this:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(A1; B1&"!C:E");
        IMPORTRANGE(A2; B2&"!C:E");
        IMPORTRANGE(A3; B3&"!C:E")}; "where Col1 is not null"; 0)
```

note that all imported sheets need to be connected separately beforehand

Comment: is there no way to not be copy-pasting thy IMPORTRANGE bit?

Comment: nope, INDIRECT and IMPORTRANGE do not work in arrayformulas

Comment: I have yet another question but I don't think it''s quite related to this one, and there's a 90 minutes cooldown on asking here, can I contact you anywhere?